# Use the value of -D parameter passed from MYSQL client inside the .sql script

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am executing below command to run my test.sql file.

```
"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\bin\mysql" -uroot -p -h localhost -P 3306 -d DB1 < C:\Users\ashishsachdeva\Desktop\test.sql
```

for creating DB1 schema

```
"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\bin\mysql" -uroot -p -h localhost -P 3306 -d DB2 < C:\Users\ashishsachdeva\Desktop\test.sql
```

for creating DB2 schema

Within my .sql file below command is repeated multiple times:-

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL
                 FROM information_schema.statistics
                WHERE table_schema = '@@DB1@@' 
                  AND index_name='idx_test' 
                  AND table_name='test')  THEN
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT idx_test UNIQUE
(
    id
);
```

I want to assign the value of -d parameter to local variable say l_schema and use it for comparison in above sql instead of @@DB1@@. This way i would be able to use the same script for setting up @@DB1@@ and @@DB2@@

Comment: Even if you can get the substitution to work, the `IF` won't work outside of a Stored Routine.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a variable, use the [DATABASE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/database/) function in your SQL.